# Uninstalling and Reinstalling NPM with a Specific Version in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins and currently working on a project that uses Jenkins for continuous integration, and I need to uninstall my current version of NPM and reinstall it with a specific version. I'm wondering if deleting the node_modules folder would resolve the issue, or if there's a better way to go about it.

I'm not sure if deleting the node_modules folder would be necessary or helpful in this case. Would deleting this folder resolve any potential conflicts with my current version of NPM and the version I'm trying to install?

Has anyone else dealt with this issue before? Is there a better way to uninstall and reinstall NPM with a specific version in a Jenkins pipeline?

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. It's a corporate Jenkins server and I don't have access to plugin configurations.

I tried this but no luck!

```
stage('Uninstall Npm') {
    steps {
        sh 'npm uninstall -g npm'
    }
}

stage('Install Specific Version of Npm') {
    steps {
        sh 'npm install -g npm@<specific_version>'
    }
}
```

Comment: You change the NPM version on Jenkins agent, it's not impact other jobs which run on the agent?

Comment: No, it won't impact other jobs if I change my NPM version. I upgraded it to the latest version and now it is not compatible with my Node.js version. As I need to keep the version of installed Node.js plugin as it is, I need to downgrade my NPM but sh 'npm uninstall -g npm' and sh 'npm install -g npm@<specific_version>' do not work.